# Suitable ADT for Graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph

What are the suitable data structures for graphs ?

I guess the answer varies on the type of graph?

in any case, any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you want an *abstract* data type, I won't mention anything about implementation.

A graph `G = <V, E>` is a set of vertices `V`, and a set of edges `E` where each element in `E` is a tuple `e = <v1, v2>`, and `v1` and `v2` are in `V`.

The following may look like Java but I'm really thinking of any sufficiently expressive language:

```
interface Graph {
    Set getVertices();
    Set getEdges();
    void addVertex(Object v);
    void addEdge(Object v1, Object v2);
    void removeVrtex(Object v);
    void removeEdge(Object v1, Object v2);
}
```

I think this is the bare minimum.  I haven't specified what is returned by `getEdges`; if the language has a native tuple type it would a set of those.  In practice you would want to add extra methods such as:

```
int getDegree(Object v);
void contractEdge(Object v1, Object v2);
boolean isIsthmus(Object v1, Object v2);  /* does removal of this edge increase the number of components? */
int numComponents();
boolean isConnected();  /* return numComponents() <= 1 */
boolean isCycle(Set path);  /* path is a set of edges. */
```

etc.

Extending this to digraphs is left as an exercise `:-)`.

Answer (score 2):

Two of the most common structures for storing graphs are [adjacency lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) and [adjacency matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). Which to use typically depends both on what you're planning to do with the graph (as one may provide more optimal manipulation/access times than the other for a given algorithm), and also on the sparseness or density of the graph (lists are more compact for sparse graphs, matrices have less relative overhead the denser the graph is).

Comment: I m aware of the adjacency list and matrix, plus there are incidency list and matrix. but what data structure goes with them?

Answer (score 1):

When the graph is sparse, a `Map<Vertex, List<Vertex>>` (1) will do. If it's dense, a 2D array may also be used (2).

See:

(1) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list

(2) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix